# CakePHP can't find 'wkhtmltopdf' when using CakePdf plugin

Tags: cakephp, wkhtmltopdf

I'm stuck on a problem which has got be stumped. I've installed the [CakePdf plugin](https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf) as per the instructions in the Read Me file. When I get to use the plugin however, I get a CakePHP error saying the following:

> Pdf engine "wkhtmltopdf" not found
>
> Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred. Stack Trace
>
> ```
> APP/Plugin/CakePdf/Pdf/CakePdf.php line 193 → CakePdf->engine(string)
> APP/Plugin/CakePdf/View/PdfView.php line 74 → CakePdf->__construct(array)
> APP/Plugin/CakePdf/View/PdfView.php line 64 → PdfView->renderer(array)
> CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 942 → PdfView->__construct(UsersController)
> CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 193 → Controller->render()
> CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 161 → Dispatcher->_invoke(UsersController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
> APP/webroot/index.php line 96 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
> ```

I've checked the binary path that CakePdf uses, and this is the following code:

```
protected $binary = '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf';
```

I've navigated to the /usr/bin/ directory, and the wkhtmltopdf binary is there. I've also used the command `wkhtmltopdf http://bbc.co.uk bbc.pdf` and it works. So I don't know why CakePHP/CakePdf can't find the plugin, even though it is located in the defined binary path?

**Update**
Here is the permissions etc for the `wkhtmltopdf` binary:

> -rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 8301444 Aug 27 08:14 wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an error in the documentation.

When you call `wkhtmltopdf` in the bootstrap.php file, instead of using:

```
'engine' => 'WkHtmlToPdf'
```

You need to use:

```
'engine' => 'CakePdf.WkHtmlToPdf'
```

instead.

This then fixes the issue.